How can I find the argument of this complex numbers under the preimage of $f(\omega)=\frac{\omega+z}{1+\overline{z}\omega}$?

I have the following problem. I have the harmonic measure $\mu_D(z,d\omega)$ and I want to compute it on the unit circle i.e. $D=\mathbb{D}$. I already have shown that for any conformal map $f$, $\mu_{f(D)}(f(z),f(V))=\mu_D(z,V)$ and that $\mu_\mathbb{D}(0,d\omega)$ is the uniform measure on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ i.e. $\mu_\mathbb{D}(0,\cdot)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$. I now want to compute $\mu_\mathbb{D}(z,\cdot)$ for $z\in \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$. Using that $f(\omega)=\frac{\omega+z}{1+\overline{z}\omega}$ is a conformal map sending $0\mapsto z$ and that $\mu_{\mathbb{D}}(z,f(V))=\mu_\mathbb{D}(0,V)$ it is enough to compute $\mu_\mathbb{D}(0, V)$.

I now want to do it for an arbitrary arc on the unit circle between two complex numbers. I fix a point $z\in \mathbb{D}$, say $z=re^{it}$ for $t\in [0, 2\pi)$ and $0<r<1$ fixed. I fixed an arbitrary arc denote it by $f(V)$. One can say that $f(V)=[e^{it_1},e^{it_2}]$ for some $t_1<t_2 \in [0, 2\pi)$. I now first want to compute the preimage $V$. Therefore I solved the following equations for $\omega_1,\omega_2\in \partial \mathbb{D}$
$$\frac{\omega_1+z}{\overline{z}\omega_1+1}=e^{it_1},\frac{\omega_2+z}{\overline{z}\omega_2+1}=e^{it_2} $$
I thus get that $V=\left[\frac{e^{it_1}-z}{1-e^{it_1}\overline{z}},\frac{e^{it_2}-z}{1-e^{it_2}\overline{z}}\right]$. But now I need the argument of this complex numbers $\frac{e^{it_1}-z}{1-e^{it_1}\overline{z}},\frac{e^{it_2}-z}{1-e^{it_2}\overline{z}}$ because I know $\mu_\mathbb{D}(0,[e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2}])=\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2\pi}$.
I don't see how to do it, I tried to compute it replacing $z=x+iy\in \mathbb{D}$ and $e^{it_k}=x_k+iy_k$ for $k=1,2$ and then split $\frac{e^{it_k}-z}{1-e^{it_k}\overline{z}}$ in it real and imaginary part say $R_k+iI_k$ and then use that $\operatorname{Arg}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{R_k}{I_k}\right)$. But I got not so far in the computation since I could not find the representation $R_k+iY_k$.
Can someone help me?

What do you mean by interval here? The circular arc between the two complex numbers (on the unit circle)?

yes sorry I mean the circular arc between two complex numbers on the unit circle @preferred_anon

Let $z=re^{it}$, $w = e^{it_1}$, and
$$
W = \frac{w-z}{1-\overline z w} = e^{it_1} \frac{1-re^{i(t-t_1)}}{1-re^{-i(t-t_1)}}.
$$
Note that the numerator and denominator are complex conjugates, and
$$
\arg(1-re^{i(t-t_1)}) = -\arg(1-re^{-i(t-t_1)}) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r\sin(t_1-t)}{1-r\cos(t_1-t)}\right).
$$
Then (given the argument of a product is the sum of the arguments)
$$
\arg(W) = t_1 + 2 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r\sin(t_1-t)}{1-r\cos(t_1-t)}\right)
$$
at least up to an integer multiple of $\pi$.  Would have to think harder about quadrants etc.

Thanks a lot, could you help me how to find out the multiple of $\pi$? Do I really need to do this or is it irrelevant because for my second $W_2$ I would have the same multiple no? So it cancels?
